# Skipping not open output file subItem error 34565

Tags: windows-10, mingw, omnet++

Platform

- OMNeT++ version: [e.g. 5.5.1]
- OS: [e.g. windows 10]

I have installed Omnet++ multiple times but it gives me the same . As soon as I open minGW it opens a command prompt window for me and I am supposed to press any key and then it would run itself to skipping not open output file and run it for as long as it can.
I have installed the folder in C://users
[this is what it shows on my command prompt after running MinGW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siVMR.png)

Comment: Try to extract OMNeT++ package using 7zip to another directory, for example c:\omnet. The name of the directory cannot contain a space. Your directory (c:\users) may need admin privileges to access. Moreover, disable realtime scanning by your anit-virus.

Comment: Thank you @JerzyD. that really helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is when you try to extract the archive.
Use 7-Zip to extract the archive to a location that has no spaces in the path.